# How to JSON serialize an object from server side and send that serialized object to client side view MVC4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, server

i am almost new in mvc5.Last two days i was trying to serialize an object from server side. I need to send the serialized object to client side. In the client side the serialized object should be De-serialized also. 
My object has six properties but i need two of them be serialized. I tried the following

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name = "myName";
p.age = 24;
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
```

Here **DataContractJsonSerializer** is not working. Please help me to figure out the problem and to pass the serialised object to client side

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just leverage the JsonResult to do that?

```
public JsonResult GetPerson() 
{
    Person P = new Person 
    {
         Name = "myName",
         Age = 24
    }

    return Json(p);
}
```

Comment: @Slicksim...Thanks a lot. But i need to do it from HttpGet/HttpPost action of a controller

Comment: That will still work, the code above is a standard mvc action.  Although, if you want to use it with a get, there is an overload to Json which takes a JsonRequestBehaviour which has AllowGet and DenyGet, so you will need to set that appropriately

Comment: Dear Slicksim... how can i de-serialize it on GetPerson's respective view? And pass it again to its Post action? Actually i have some @Html.hidden field in my view(.cshtml) file. I want to get rid of this hidden fields. i want to fill my hidden fields from that json serialize object.

Comment: You could set the value of the hidden to the json, but then you'd need to deserialise it yourself in the controller.  sounds like you need to rethink how you are approaching the problem, you are fighting the framework there by the sounds of it